# Result of lottery

Tags: php, cron, sleep

I am developing a lottery website but stuck with one problem. So please help me out. Here i am explaining the situation:Here is the link of lottery page http://studysesh.org/greenstreak/mark/lottery1.php. The lottery page having  3 lotteries with different result of time. For example first lottery result out after every six hours, 2nd will result out after 24 hours and 3rd one will result out after 7 days. I have coded all functionality in php. When site is open in any browser,its check for result of Lottery in every second with Ajax request. But, my problem is that if i close the browser than it will not check any value. I have used the cron job of one minute for following code:

```
    $select = mysql_query("Select * from tbl_rooms where room_status='1'"); 
$countRows = mysql_num_rows($select);

if($countRows>0)
{
   while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($select))
    {

$date1 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 

$date2 = $rows['room_end_date'];

$date1Timestamp = strtotime($date1);
$date2Timestamp = strtotime($date2);

if($date1 < $date2){
   //convert the date back to underscore format if needed when printing it out.
  // echo '1 is small='.$date1.','.date('d_m_y',$date1);

//Calculate the difference.


  $difference = $date2Timestamp - $date1Timestamp;
  //echo $difference;
    if($difference < 60)
    {

        sleep($difference);

    $room_title=$rows['room_title'];
    $room_id=$rows['room_id'];

    if($room_title == 'Quick Six')
    {
        $update_date= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('6 hour'));
        mysql_query("UPDATE `tbl_rooms` SET `room_end_date`='$update_date' WHERE `room_title`='Quick Six'"); 
    }   
    if($room_title == 'Daily Draw')
    {
        $update_date= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('24 hour'));
        mysql_query("UPDATE `tbl_rooms` SET `room_end_date`='$update_date' WHERE `room_title`='Daily Draw'"); 
    }
    if($room_title == 'Lucky Seven')
    {
        $update_date= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('7 day'));
        mysql_query("UPDATE `tbl_rooms` SET `room_end_date`='$update_date' WHERE `room_title`='Lucky Seven'"); 
    }

        $buyroom_query=mysql_query("SELECT distinct `u_id` FROM `tbl_buyroom`  where `room_id`='$room_id'");
        $buyroom_count=mysql_num_rows($buyroom_query);

        if($buyroom_count >= 5)
        {
            $room_coin=round($rows['room_price']*0.65);
            $winner_query=mysql_query("SELECT distinct `u_id` FROM `tbl_buyroom`  where `room_id`='$room_id' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5 ;");

            $i=0;
            while($winner_id=mysql_fetch_assoc($winner_query))
            {
                $i++;
                $user_id=$winner_id['u_id'];
                $a[]=$winner_id['u_id'];
                $user_query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tbl_users` where `id`='$user_id'");
                $result_query=mysql_fetch_assoc($user_query);
                $price=$result_query['total_coin'];
                if($i==1)
                {
                    $win_id1=$user_id;
                    $user_coin=0;
                    $user_coin=round($room_coin*0.50);
                    $win_coin=$price+$user_coin;
                    mysql_query("UPDATE `tbl_users` SET `total_coin`='$win_coin' WHERE id='$user_id'");
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tbl_rooms_win`(`room_id`, `u_id`, `win_date`, `price`, `win_status`) VALUES ('$room_id','$user_id','$date1','$user_coin','1')");
                    success_mail($user_id, $room_title, $user_coin, $win_coin);
                    $win[]=$win_coin;
                }
                if($i==2)
                {
                    $win_id2=$user_id;
                    $user_coin=0;
                    $user_coin=round($room_coin*0.25);
                    $win_coin=$price+$user_coin;
                    mysql_query("UPDATE `tbl_users` SET `total_coin`='$win_coin' WHERE id='$user_id'");
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tbl_rooms_win`(`room_id`, `u_id`, `win_date`, `price`, `win_status`) VALUES ('$room_id','$user_id','$date1','$user_coin','1')");
                    success_mail($user_id, $room_title, $user_coin, $win_coin);
                    $win[]=$win_coin;
                }
                if($i==3)
                {
                    $win_id3=$user_id;
                    $user_coin=0;
                    $user_coin=round($room_coin*0.13);
                    $win_coin=$price+$user_coin;
                    mysql_query("UPDATE `tbl_users` SET `total_coin`='$win_coin' WHERE id='$user_id'");
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tbl_rooms_win`(`room_id`, `u_id`, `win_date`, `price`, `win_status`) VALUES ('$room_id','$user_id','$date1','$user_coin','1')");
                    success_mail($user_id, $room_title, $user_coin, $win_coin);
                    $win[]=$win_coin;
                }
                if($i==4)
                {
                    $win_id4=$user_id;
                    $user_coin=0;
                    $user_coin=round($room_coin*0.06);
                    $win_coin=$price+$user_coin;
                    mysql_query("UPDATE `tbl_users` SET `total_coin`='$win_coin' WHERE id='$user_id'");
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tbl_rooms_win`(`room_id`, `u_id`, `win_date`, `price`, `win_status`) VALUES ('$room_id','$user_id','$date1','$user_coin','1')");
                    success_mail($user_id, $room_title, $user_coin, $win_coin);
                    $win[]=$win_coin;
                }
                if($i==5)
                {
                    $win_id5=$user_id;
                    $user_coin=0;
                    $user_coin=round($room_coin*0.06);
                    $win_coin=$price+$user_coin;
                    mysql_query("UPDATE `tbl_users` SET `total_coin`='$win_coin' WHERE id='$user_id'");
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tbl_rooms_win`(`room_id`, `u_id`, `win_date`, `price`, `win_status`) VALUES ('$room_id','$user_id','$date1','$user_coin','1')");
                    success_mail($user_id, $room_title, $user_coin, $win_coin);
                    $win[]=$win_coin;
                }


            }
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM `tbl_buyroom` WHERE `room_id`='$room_id'");

        }
        else
        {
            while($no_winner=mysql_fetch_assoc($buyroom_query))
            {
                $uid=$no_winner['u_id'];
                nowinner_mail($uid, $room_title);
                $result="No winner";
            }   
        }
    }   
}

}
}
```

In the above  code, i have used sleep method.This works perfectly for sometime but many times, if it will sleep for 1 lottery result in the mean time another result will be coming with less seconds of sleep. So it stops working for one lottery. I hope you understand my problem. Please help me out to resolve it

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Ok i will take care of it.  but for now can you provide me the solution of my problem?